# How to emit a Qt signal daily at a given time?

Tags: qt, time

I need to notify some objects to clear their cache at new day begins. So, I could create QTimer or something similar and check every ms that now midnight +-5ms or not, but it's not a good idea for me.
Is there(in QT) any standard mechanisms to get notified about this event without allocating any new object? Something static or living since application's initialization like qApp?
What would you do in situation like this where you need to do something at 00:00?

UPD:
I'm looking for fast enough solution. Fast means that I need to clear container in slot as quick as it possible, 'cause since midnight data in the container become invalid. So, there is some other timer which shots every 100ms for instance and it trying to get data from container. I need to clear container with invalid data right before any possible try of getting access.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest solution does indeed utilize a timer. Polling for the passage of time in not only unnecessary, but would be horrible performance-wise. Simply start the actions when the midnight strikes:

```
static int msecsTo(const QTime & at) {
  const int msecsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  int msecs = QTime::currentTime().msecsTo(at);
  if (msecs < 0) msecs += msecsPerDay;
  return msecs;
}

// C++11

void runAt(const std::function<void> & job, const QTime & at, Qt::TimerType type = Qt::VeryCoarseTimer) {
  // Timer ownership prevents timer leak when the thread terminates.
  auto timer = new QTimer(QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance());
  timer->start(msecsTo(at), type);
  QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=job, &timer]{
    job();
    timer->deleteLater();
  });
}  

runAt([&]{ object->member(); }, QTime(...));

// C++98

void scheduleSlotAt(QObject * obj, const char * member, const QTime & at, Qt::TimerType type = Qt::VeryCoarseTimer) {
  QTimer::singleShot(msecsTo(at), type, obj, member);
}

class MyObject : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  void scheduleCleanup() {
    scheduleSlotAt(this, SLOT(atMidnight()), QTime(0, 0));
  }
  Q_SLOT void atMidnight() {
    // do some work here
    ...
    scheduleCleanup();
  }
public:
  MyObject(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
    ...
    scheduleCleanup();
  }
};
```

> there is some other timer which shots every 100ms for instance and it trying to get data from container.

Since both of these timers presumably run in the same thread, they execute serially and it doesn't matter how much "later" either one is. They won't both run at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. It's good answer. Hope this will work, but I think that it could be not enough fast. Will it be an queued or direct connection?

Comment: @cassandradied It doesn't matter to you what connection type is it.  You're doing it once a day at a given time (say midnight). Even if it ran a minute late, it would be fine. As it is, the time it runs at is rounded to the nearest second. Your concerns are grossly misplaced. You have to be very clear about why you think it won't be fast enough (and what you even mean by it not being fast enough). I think you fundamentally misunderstand something about how Qt works.

Comment: it's only a good answer, not the best and not a solution for me, so, this is why I don't upvote or mark accepted. Also, see update. And, yes, I could solve my problem with addition synchronization variable and timer, but I'm looking for different possible solutions.

Comment: @cassandradied Being careful about *accepts* like you say you are is good, but it's usually good to be liberal with *upvotes* for the answers to your own questions. If it's a good, honest answer offering a solution, it deserves an upvote from the asker, even if that solution is not used in the end. You can upvote more than one answer, they don't have to be "the best" for upvote.