# Exucuting functions in a specific time QT

Tags: qt, qtimer

well I'm a working on QT project and I want to play music at a specific time where the user is going to enter that time by lineEdit for example its 9:00:00PM and the user wants to play the music at 10:00:00PM

```
void musique::play_music(QMediaPlayer *player, QString nomm)
{
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\Users\\Louay\\Desktop\\Music\\"+nomm+".mp3"));
player->setVolume(100);
player->play();
}
```

this is the function to play the music(it works correctly) .. but how can I excute that function at the entered time.. can anyone help me plase I checked some topics but I coudnt understand them very well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481959/how-to-emit-a-qt-signal-daily-at-a-given-time

Comment: ***please do not duplicate that topic cause I really need the answer, thanks*** Remember this is not a forum. Your question is here to help future readers with the same problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc its not the same thing I want to do with the topic u did put .. he wants to make the a daily signal where he did put the time in "code" while I want to excute the function not daily but for just once in a specific time that its given after the progam is executed

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA It is the same, stop the timer when you do not want it to repeat itself.

Comment: Make the timer a single shot with `setSingleShot(bool singleShot)`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop

Answer (score 0):

You can use QTime in your work flow. QTime takes the time from system local time.

```
QLineEdit *usertime = new QLineEdit("");

if(QTime::currentTime().toString("HH:mm:ss:zzz") == usertime->text())
{
   play_music(bla,bla);
}
```